# The minimum "height" of a convex polygon on $\mathbb{N}^2$.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, oeis

I've defined a new OEIS sequence but I'm having trouble figuring out a reasonable way to compute more terms.

[A285521](https://oeis.org/A285521):

> Table read by rows: the $n$-th row gives the lexicographically earliest sequence of length $n$ such that the convex hull of $(1, a(1)), \ldots, (n, a(n))$ is an $n$-gon with minimum height.

The table begins:

$$\begin{array}{l}
    1\\
    1,1\\
    1,1,2\\
    1,1,2,2\\
    1,1,3,2,3\\
    1,2,1,3,2,3\\
    1,3,1,4,4,2,3\\
    2,3,1,1,4,4,2,3\\
\end{array}$$

For example rows 5–8 are represented like this:

$$\begin{array}{ccccc|cccccc|ccccccc|cccccccc}
5\colon&&&&&
6\colon&&&&&&
7\colon&&&&&&&
8\colon&&&&&&&\\
 & & & & & & & & & & & & & &.&.& & & & & & &.&.& &\\
 & &.& &.& & & &.& &.& &.& & & & &.& &.& & & & & &.\\
 & & &.& & &.& & &.& & & & & & &.& &.& & & & & &.&\\
.&.& & & &.& &.& & & &.& &.& & & & & & &.&.& & & &\\
\end{array}$$

By an exhaustiveness check, I've confirmed that the 9-gon in the ninth row must have a height greater than five, and I can construct one by hand with height six.

Any ideas on how to determine (or put a bound on) the minimum height required for the $n$-th row?

Any heuristics or tricks that can be used to compute more terms of the sequence? (for example, no value can appear more than twice in a single row.)

Comment: What is wrong with $1, 3, 4, 1, 5, 5, 2, 4, 3$ for $n = 9$?

Comment: On inspection that looks good to me; perhaps I did my check incorrectly.

Comment: How many rows do you need to compute? I guess rather straightforward brute force search would give you 11 or 12 rows within an hour. Also I can describe a promising cutoff. (I can't give any guarantee, but hope to overcome $n = 20$ in reasonable time.)

Comment: I'd like to compute as many rows as possible! Knowing just that each row contains a given value at most twice, and assuming that the height of a 2n-gon is n-1, then there are $\prod_{i=0}^{n/2 - 2}{n-2i \choose 2}$ sequences to enumerate. But a clever sieve can probably remove the majority of these.

Comment: I have some motivation to think that $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{h(n)}{n} = +\infty$, where $h(n)$ is minimum height of convex $n$-gon.

Comment: Interesting! The growth of http://oeis.org/A156831 would make me think the h(n)/n <= 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried the following idea. At first we take a certain value $k$ of height to test whether it is reachable. Then like in [Graham scan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan#Notes) algorithm modification called Andrew's Monotone Chain Algorithm we will build lower and upper bounds of convex hull moving from left to right. Moving from left to right for each next point we take all possible $k$ variants, but move further to the right only if it is possible to add this point to either upper or lower bound without removing any other point from this bound. (There is a special case for the first and the last points which should be added to both lower and upper bounds.)

I've implemented this idea, it computed the first 16 rows in 38 seconds, took 687 more to compute the 17th row and 934 more to compute the 18th row.

$$\begin{array}{l|l}
n & \pi_n \\\hline
2 & 1, 1 \\
3 & 1, 1, 2 \\
4 & 1, 1, 2, 2 \\
5 & 1, 1, 3, 2, 3 \\
6 & 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3 \\
7 & 1, 3, 1, 4, 4, 2, 3 \\
8 & 2, 3, 1, 1, 4, 4, 2, 3 \\
9 & 1, 3, 4, 1, 5, 5, 2, 4, 3 \\
10 & 3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 5, 5, 2, 4, 3 \\
11 & 2, 1, 5, 6, 1, 7, 7, 2, 6, 3, 4 \\
12 & 4, 3, 6, 2, 7, 7, 1, 1, 6, 2, 5, 4 \\
13 & 2, 4, 1, 7, 8, 1, 9, 9, 2, 8, 3, 4, 6 \\
14 & 4, 6, 7, 2, 8, 1, 1, 9, 9, 2, 8, 3, 4, 6 \\
15 & 3, 5, 2, 8, 9, 1, 1, 11, 11, 2, 10, 3, 4, 8, 7 \\
16 & 5, 4, 8, 9, 2, 10, 1, 1, 11, 11, 2, 10, 3, 4, 8, 7 \\
17 & 4, 3, 8, 2, 11, 12, 1, 1, 14, 14, 2, 13, 3, 4, 11, 7, 9\\
18 & 6, 8, 4, 11, 12, 2, 13, 1, 1, 14, 14, 2, 13, 3, 4, 11, 7, 9\\
19 & 5, 4, 10, 12, 2, 15, 16, 1, 1, 17, 17, 2, 16, 3, 4, 14, 13, 8, 10\\
20 & 8, 10, 5, 4, 14, 15, 2, 16, 1, 1, 17, 17, 2, 16, 3, 4, 14, 13, 8, 10\\
21 & 7, 9, 4, 3, 14, 2, 17, 18, 1, 1, 20, 20, 2, 19, 3, 4, 17, 16, 8, 13, 11\\
22 & 10, 8, 13, 5, 4, 17, 18, 2, 19, 1, 1, 20, 20, 2, 19, 3, 4, 17, 16, 8, 13, 11\\
\end{array}$$

Note that $h(11) - h(10) = h(13) - h(12) = h(15) - h(14) = 2$ and $h(17) - h(16) = 3$ where $h(n)$ is the minimum height of $n$-gon that indirectly confirms my conjecture about unlimited growth of $\frac{h(n)}n$.

Another interesting note is that $\pi_{n}$ has rather long common suffix with $\pi_{n - 1}$ for even $n$, with an exception of $n = 12$.

P. S. I would clarify in description of sequence that we need strictly convex polygon, because otherwise there is a trivial polygon of zero height.

P. P. S. It is easy to see that the sequence [oeis.org/A156831](http://oeis.org/A156831) mentioned in comments counts identical permutation that gives degenerate convex hull however its perimeter contains all points.

Comment: Taking only the first $\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2} \right\rfloor$ values for the first point speeds up computation approximately $1.5$ times, I'll keep it running during holidays and expect to get at least two more rows at Wednesday.

Comment: I've independently confirmed up to a(13). I'm going to go ahead and add your values to the OEIS sequence.

Comment: You can wait for $\pi_{19}$ and $\pi_{20}$.

Comment: Perhaps you already noticed this, but it looks like $\pi_{2n}$ has rotational symmetry for all known values. If this can be proven for all values, I reckon that it could speed up even computation. And if the observation about the suffix can be qualified and proven, then it might speed up computation for all rows.

Comment: That's a good observation. Also it raises several intesting questions about structure of pentagons. I guess you may ask new question about the polygon properties, not about algorithm.

Comment: @PeterKagey I've edited the answer and added three more rows. They confirm three conjectures about symmetry, about long common suffix and about growth of $\frac{h(n)}n$.